# Don't display those tag suggestions which are already in the list

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

When I start typing in text box to add a tag to question or *Favorite Tags* list, those tags are also suggested which are already in the list.

I am able to add a tag to question twice. This isn't a big problem as this wouldn't be a issue after submission, but I don't like it with *Favorite Tags*. Unlike question tags, list of *Favorite Tags* can be big. And, in big list, I always add a tag from suggestion which is already in the list just to see nothing is happening. Its also annoying when I see a suggestion of a tag I added year ago and I think: What!!! How am I not following THIS tag?